# Can I corrupt my Arduino if it's unplugged during an upload?

Tags: uploading, safety, avrdude

When messing around with code and uploading a sketch to my Arduino board, I almost accidentally pulled out the USB cord. Everything is fine, but then I started thinking what would've happened if I had pulled it out.

How safe is avrdude? Could it damage or brick the board? I'd imagine that you would just have to upload code to it again... but what would happen before you upload the new code? I've seen something about how you can always upload new code if the bootloader is intact, but I would imagine that there would be some problems. If this were to happen, should I unplug everything connected in case Arduino writes a HIGH to an input (or similar) that would damage the component?

Comment: So I accidentally did this to my Arduino Nano 33 BLE and now my computer cant see it.. I tried restarting my computer, hitting the reset button on the board, unplugging and plugging it back in and still nothing. Is there a way to revive it?

Comment: @Coy, use double reset to activate the bootloader

Answer (score 7, accepted):

AVRDUDE does not actually *perform* the write, it merely *directs* it. The actual writes are performed either by the bootloader or by the ISP firmware/hardware within the MCU itself.

With the bootloader it depends on how itself is coded, but at worst it would finish off the flash byte or page or EEPROM page zero- or one-filled and then fail to communicate further with AVRDUDE, aborting programming.

With ISP, the page write command would never be received and the programming would be aborted at the last full page. Fuse bytes are done singly and so programming a single fuse can be viewed as an atomic operation.

In either case, a chip erase operation should reset the MCU to a known working state, fuse changes excepted.

Comment: *With the bootloader it depends on how itself is coded, but at worst it would finish off the flash byte or page or EEPROM page zero- or one-filled and then fail to communicate further with AVRDUDE, aborting programming.* Wait... how could it abort it if there is no power?

Comment: @AnnonomusPerson: External power, USB/serial programming.

Comment: What if I'm only using USB power? That doesn't answer my question about your answer.

Comment: If all you have is USB power then everything just stops. The bootloader is unable to finish the current byte. But that won't damage any flash cells.

Answer (score 2):

One safety feature that hasn't been mentioned so far is that the ATmega328 has a set of lock bits that prevent read/write access to certain areas. To the best of my knowledge, the way Arduinos are set up, those bits are always set to prevent writing to the boot loader area unless the "Burn Bootloader" command is currently active, and since you can only use that command with an external programmer, you can always write a new bootloader if something goes wrong.

I think the only way of bricking the board (in the sense of leaving the MCU in a state that is functional, yet almost irrepairably unresponsive) is writing bad fuse settings.

Answer (score 1):

It should be fine.

Most boards don't require you to reupload the bootloader every time you upload a sketch, so your program will be corrupted but your bootloader won't. I assume the bootloader is similar to the bootloader on other chips I have seen<sup>*</sup>, it will stop execution if the code doesn't work properly. I would also think that the micro would not accept a transmission if it's checksum is missing.

I wouldn't try it if I were you, but you can be a little less cautious about this sort of thing.

<sup>*</sup>: the Propellor chip, among others

Comment: Very few embedded MCUs have any sort of error catching facilities. If by `the code doesn't work properly` you mean the code in the program memory is invalid/corrupted, you are incorrect. The MCU will just happily continue executing the invalid code, leading to undetermined behaviour. If you mean the bootloader will ignore invalid commands, that is entirely dependent on the bootloader.

Comment: Yep, nothing to catch or check for errors in user code in Optiboot. This is what the watchdog timer is for.